# Making related list as mandatory

Tags: validation, related-list

This could be a stupid question. please apologize my lack of knowledge in salesforce. I am still new to the salesforce world and learning...

Is it even possible to make a related list as mandatory through Standard salesforce functionality..

example: when i create an opportunity i need to make an related list mandatory...
after i hit save, i should be presented with a screen to enter the related list values..

I believe this is possible through customization (VF page and APEX controller); but is it possible to do it in a standard functionality.

Answer (score 8):

You can do something like this with standard functionality. It doesn't fit your requirement perfectly, but may work.

1. Create a roll-up summary field that counts the number of detail records.
2. Create a validation rule that prevents the user from changing the opportunity stage until the number of detail records is greater than 0.

This lets you create the record with no related list, but then you have to add it before you can work the opportunity.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a custom button to get to the edit page, and then using the SaveURL to direct the user to the url of the related list once they save it.

Steps required:

1. Have a custom button instead of the normal button
2. Have this button link to the page to create that object:
   (`<domain>.salesforce.com/<three letter code>/e?`)
3. Have the saveURL parameter in that url, with a link to the object to be edited.

Hope this helps! I'm sure there are other solutions, but this is the first that comes to my mind, and gives you the most control over your objects and how the user interacts with them.

[Blog post on SaveUrl Hacking](http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-basics-with-returl-saveurl-and-cancelurl.html)

[Url Hacking Primer](http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html)